# mysql query to obtain rows for weeks of the year that do not have data

Tags: mysql

I have to display the rows for weeks that do not have results (based on the time stamp column in my db). I created a temporary 'weeks' table and formed the query below based on other SO Q/A's:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE weeks (weekNo INT);

INSERT INTO weeks (weekNo) VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19), (20), (21), (22), (23), (24), (25), (26), (27), (28), (29), (30), (31), (32), (33), (34), (35), (36), (37), (38), (39), (40), (41), (42), (43), (44), (45), (46), (47), (48), (49), (50), (51), (52), (53), (54);

SELECT 
   WeekNo, 
   SUBDATE(DATE(i.TimeStamp), 
   INTERVAL WEEKDAY(DATE(i.TimeStamp)) DAY) AS date_of_week, 
   COUNT(distinct PatientID) PatientCount,
   COUNT(distinct PatientID, AcquisitionDate) StudyCount
FROM image_info i 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN weeks w ON WEEK(DATE(i.TimeStamp)) = WeekNo 
GROUP BY WeekNo;
```

and that gets me here:

```
WeekNo    date_of_week    PatientCount    StudyCount
------    ------------    ------------    ----------
5         2017-01-30      19              19
6         2017-02-06      28              28
9         2017-02-27      15              15
```

but I would like to see this:

```
WeekNo    date_of_week    PatientCount    StudyCount
------    ------------    ------------    ----------
1         2017-01-01      0               0
2         2017-01-08      0               0
3         2017-01-15      0               0
4         2017-01-22      0               0
5         2017-01-30      19              19
6         2017-02-06      28              28
7         2017-02-12      0               0
8         2017-02-19      0               0
9         2017-02-27      15              15
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong with the query?

Comment: What's in image_info? Seems to me like your join is incorect.

Comment: Can you post some sample `image_info` data?

Answer (score 0):

try to invert the tables on the query.

use first week table and left outer join it with image_info table.

Comment: `x LEFT OUTER JOIN y` is the same as `y RIGHT OUTER JOIN x`.

Answer (score 0):

You are only grouping on the first column, but you have four columns, and you only have aggregate functions on the last two.  Generally, you would want to group by on the first two columns.  Also, there is no way for the sql to give you values for column 2, for rows where there is no record in image_info.  That is, SUBDATE(DATE(i.TimeStamp... evaluates to NULL for the empty weeks, not to the values you want to display with each week.  So...

Your best bet is to calculate column 2 from the week number in the weeks table, and make sure you include it in your group by column.  Also, notice I took out week 0.  Normally you don't have a week 0.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE weeks (weekNo INT);

INSERT INTO weeks (weekNo) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19), (20), (21), (22), (23), (24), (25), (26), (27), (28), (29), (30), (31), (32), (33), (34), (35), (36), (37), (38), (39), (40), (41), (42), (43), (44), (45), (46), (47), (48), (49), (50), (51), (52), (53), (54);

SELECT 
    w.weekNo,
    ADDDATE('2017-01-01', INTERVAL (w.weekNo-1)*7 DAY) AS date_of_week, 
    COUNT(distinct PatientID) PatientCount,
    COUNT(distinct PatientID, AcquisitionDate) StudyCount
FROM image_info i 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN weeks w ON WEEK(DATE(i.editDate)) = w.weekNo 
GROUP BY WeekNo, ADDDATE('2017-01-01', INTERVAL (w.weekNo-1)*7 DAY)
ORDER BY WeekNo;
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` are symmetic. If you use `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, you put the tables in the opposite order.

Comment: @Barmar I just realized that this WILL do the exact same thing.  In fact, Mysql converts all RIGHT OUTER joins to the corresponding LEFT OUTER joins, with the tables reversed.  So, his query should work.  Hmmmm!!!???

Comment: I think I see the problem.